# Неоднозначный вызов методов Where

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public static List<Premium> GetUserPremium(ulong UserId)
        {
            using var db = new SqliteDbContext();
            return db.Premiums.Where(x => x.UserId == UserId).ToList();
        }
```

что это? можете объяснить как пофиксить? прошу помогите пофиксить

Comment: Студия вам говорит "Ей, человек, я не понимаю из какого пространства имен ты хочешь вызвать Where, их несколько!". Наведите на место ошибки и она предложит выбрать нужное.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ извините, что так поздно пишу, но студия предлагает только цепочку вызовов, это не решает мою проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Как понимаю, возникает проблема, программа не понимает какую именно перегрузку `Where` использовать, т.к. БД возвращает один из трех типов и у всех есть метод `Where`.

Решилось приведением к одному из возможных типов перед вызовом `Where`:

```
 public static List<Premium> GetUserPremium(ulong UserId)
    {
        using var db = new SqliteDbContext();
        return ((IEnumerable<Premium>)db.Premiums).Where(x => x.UserId == UserId).ToList();
    }
```